# How to store Video on my device on android 11

Tags: react-native, permissions, android-permissions, react-native-permissions

I am trying to use https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions for storing the video but my video is not getting stored and I am using android 11 I have given the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
How can I store the video on my device?